# Need an example of using design by contract in Symfony

Tags: symfony, interface, contract

I am trying to build an API proxy for an external API in my Symfony app. So my Symfony app uses design by contract principle. So a backend service to query the external API.

I need to use "coding by contract" principle with an interface so that the API is easily exchangeable with other services.

I am looking for an example which illustrates this concept.

Comment: Right now, I am just using standard php curl with a parameter I pass to the external autocomplete API.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: need an  example for design by contract in symfony. My use case is as above.